# Get all the values from the "for loop" run

Tags: matlab

I have some *.dat files in a folder, I would like to extract a particular column (8th column) from all of the files and put into a excel file. I have run a for loop, but it only gives me the results of final run (i.e. if there are 10 number of files, it only returns me 8th column of the 10th files).

```
data = cell(numel(files),1);
for i = 1:numel(files)
    fid = fopen(fullfile(pathToFolder,files(i).name), 'rt');
    H = textscan(fid, '%s', 4, 'Delimiter','\n'); 
    C = textscan(fid, repmat('%f ',1,48), 'Delimiter',' ', ... 
    'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true, 'CollectOutput',true); 
     fclose(fid);
     H = H = H{1}; C = C{1};
     data{i} = C;
     B = C(:,8);
end
```

Looking for your help on this.

It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `B` each iteration. `B(:,i)` will put each column 8 of `C` in a column of `B`.